# Why does JS function show in block scope if it is hoisted in global scope?

Tags: javascript, scope, lexical-scope

I was playing around with JS scopes to get a better understanding of the concept. Doing that I wrote the following script:

```js
{
  let a;
  function x() {
    let p;
    var q;
  }
}

x();
```

Surprisingly, when debugging in the Chrome dev console, I realized that if I  stop the script at line 2 or `let a`, I  can see the block scope having both variable `a` and function `x` as visible in screenshot 1.

Also, on logging `window.x` outputs `undefined` However, as soon as I jump on to the next breakpoint which is line 4 or `let p`, the block scope is no longer there and a `local` scope is created. Now, on logging `window.x` outputs the function definition.

Now as I  understand, since I  am able to call `x()` from the global scope means that the function declaration is available in the global scope. Then why isn't the function binding available before the creation of function's execution context (if it is hoisted to global scope)?  And why does writing `x()` at the top of the block output `TypeError: x is not a function`?

[image: screenshot 1]

**Note:** I am not writing functions like this anywhere, i just wrote this script to test my understanding of scopes. Apologies if this is a wrong way of writing functions.

EDIT per comments:

Chrome and FF show `undefined` while Safari shows function definition.

```js
console.log(x); // logs undefined
{
  let a;
  function x() {
    let p;
    var q;
  }
}

x();
```

Comment: I really recommend reading YDKJS:

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/README.md

Comment: this: "_Then why isn't the function binding available before the creation of function's execution context_" - it is - prior to your openning `{`, add `console.log(x);` and it will log the function definition.

Comment: @RandyCasburn i tried and it just prints `undefined`. That is pretty much my question as to why before the creation of function execution context, the value of x on window is `undefined`?

Comment: May I edit your question to put this into a stacksnippet?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Running the code snippet shows `undefined` instead of the function definition

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, I see in Chrome & FF it returns undefined. In Safari it returns the function definition.

Comment: [I can write an answer, but I have no ref to the spec] MDN says, that function definitions are "[...] hoisted to the top of the enclosing function or global scope". For non-function scopes it seems to be browser dependent (MDN only talks about the if scope, but I guess `{ ... }` results in the same scope). For some it appears to be hoisted to the top of the global scope (Safari), for some it seems to be hoisted to the top of the local scope. However, I guess, that in all browsers, at least inside the scope it is hosted to the top (e.g. if you do `console.log(x)` right before or after `let a`).

Comment: Always use strict mode to not get confused by legacy behaviour :-)